# on Submit of form transmit the data and open a PDF file

Tags: forms, vue.js, nuxt.js

On submitting a form after HTML validation I need to send data to salesforce and open a link to the PDF file. The form is in a modal and receives the data from the parent component.

```
<form
  class="mt-6"
  @submit.prevent="submitForm(true)"
>
<button type="submit"><a :href="'/cms/+data.id+'.pdf' /></button>
</form>
```

```
methods: {
    submitForm() {
      console.log(
        'Name is ' +
          this.user.name +
          ' and the email id is ' +
          this.user.email +
          ' and the download file ID is ' +
          this.data.id
      )
    }
  }
```

Would `window.open` be a solution in the submit function ? How should I call this after the data is transmitted.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what sending data to salesforce mean exactly, but I will assume it is just a simple http post call. In that case, there are multiple ways to do this, the simples one I can think of is:

```
methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      try {
         await sendDataToSalesforce();
         window.open('path.to.pdf');
      } catch(err) {
         // handle error
      }
    }
  }
```

Another solution would be by using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).